# Unwanted Noise element during dilation

Tags: c, image, image-processing, mathematical-morphology, image-morphology

I'm applying the dilation operation on a binary ricegrain picture. When the structuring element used has size 9x9, the noise particles get enlarged, which is logical. But when I use a structuring element of size 15x15, i get new noise particles adjacent to the original noise particles. This is vry confusing as i can't why this is happening. The stucturing element is a nxn matrix with all 1's. The images have been attached for reference.

Reference image:
[image]

Dilated image (9x9 SE):
[image]

Dilated image (15x15 SE):
[image]
Please help!!

Code:

```
void DilateBinary(Mat Image, Mat& op, double* SE, int m){
op=Image.clone();
double pixelvalue;

int limit=(m-1)/2;
for(int y = limit; y < (Image.rows - limit); y++)
            {
                for(int x = limit; x < (Image.cols - limit); x++)
                {
                    double max=0.0;
                    //printf("Input pixel: %u \n",Image.at<unsigned char>(y,x));
                    for(int j = -limit; j <=limit ; j++)
                    {
                        for(int i = -limit; i <=limit ; i++)
                        {
                            if(*(SE + (j+1)*m + (i+1) ) > 0)
                            {
                                pixelvalue = (*(SE + (j+1)*m + ((2*limit)-(i+1)) )) * (Image.at<unsigned char>(y+j,x+i));
                                //printf("%f",pixelvalue);
                                if (pixelvalue>127)
                                    max=255.0;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    op.at<uchar>(y,x) = max;
                    //printf("Output pixel: %u \n",op.at<unsigned char>(y,x));
                    //printf("Modified pixel= %f %d\n",pixelvalue,cvRound(pixelvalue));

                }
            }
```

Note: SE is the pointer to the mask/SE i'm using. & m is 9 for 9x9 SE, 15 for 15x15 SE.........

Comment: So what is your question exactly? Why is this happening or how can you get rid of them? Also please tag the programming language you're using. Is it Matlab? Thanks!

Comment: i believe it should not be happening. if its right, then why is it happening. If wrong, then wh is it happening and how do i correct it.

Comment: I'm using C. the code has been inserted in the statement.

Comment: The indexing into the mask looks wrong, you're going to get negative indexes.

Comment: i'm pretty sure indexing is right. it gives correct results upto 9x9 SE. i'm getting error (if it is one) only for 15x15 SE.

Comment: although you could replace" ((2*limit)-(i+1))" by "(i+1))". it'll be the same since SE is a symmteric matrix with all 1's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The culprit is your `if` statement inside the second nested `for` loop blocks:

```
for(int j = -limit; j <=limit ; j++) {
    for(int i = -limit; i <=limit ; i++) {
        if(*(SE + (j+1)*m + (i+1) ) > 0) {
            pixelvalue = (*(SE + (j+1)*m + ((2*limit)-(i+1)) ))  (Image.at<unsigned char>(y+j,x+i));
            if (pixelvalue>127)
                max=255.0;
        }
    }
}
```

The way you are indexing into your structuring element assumes that it is a 3 x 3 mask, because you are expecting that `i` and `j` hover from `-1` to `1`.  Mark Ransom is correct in his assessment in that you would have indices with negative values.  Try setting `m = 15`, which is where your problem lies.  This means that `limit = 7` and then start with the beginning of this loop see what row and column you are accessing as you are trying to access the mask with row-major linear indices.

If `limit = 7`, that means at the beginning, `j = -7, i = -7` and so `(j+1)*m = (-7+1)*15 = -90`.  Also `(2*limit) - (i+1) = (2*7) - (-7+1) = 20`.  This ultimately means that you are trying to access the memory location of `SE - 90 + 20 = SE - 70` so you're actually assessing the memory location 70 bytes (assuming `unsigned char`) away from the origin of your structuring element, and not the top left corner of the structuring element... so are you sure you wrote that code right?  I'm surprised you haven't gotten any segmentation faults yet.  You may have lucked out with the `9 x 9` because the row offset is negative, but the column offset will be positive and they may be equal in magnitude, so you probably lucked out with accessing all of the structuring elements then, but this certainly won't be true for higher mask sizes.

In order to ensure that you cover **all** of the mask coefficients, you need to change the offset to `+limit`, not `+1`.  I also don't understand the `2*limit` inside the `if` statement.  You can just access the mask element directly.  Therefore, you need to do this:

```
for(int j = -limit; j <=limit ; j++) {
    for(int i = -limit; i <=limit ; i++) {
        if(*(SE + (j+limit)*m + (i+limit) ) > 0) {
            pixelvalue = (*(SE + (j+limit)*m + (i+limit) )) * (Image.at<unsigned char>(y+j,x+i));
            if (pixelvalue>127)
                max=255.0;
        }
    }
}
```

However, if I can suggest something, because you are doing morphological binary dilation, you only have to check to see if any pixels in your structuring element are touching a white pixel.  Because this is a square structuring element, this will be even easier. Essentially, in a `m x m` pixel neighbourhood, if any pixel is non-zero, then you'd set the output to 255 and break out of the loop.  A small optimization to your code could be:

```
for(int j = -limit; j <=limit ; j++) {
    for(int i = -limit; i <=limit ; i++) {
        pixelValue = (*(SE + (j+limit)*m + (i+limit) )); // Get structuring element value
        pixelValue *= (Image.at<unsigned char>(y+j,x+i)); // Obtain corresponding intensity
        if (pixelValue != 0) { // If non-zero, set output to max and break
            max = 255.0;
            i = limit + 1; j = limit + 1; // break out of loop
        }
    }
}
```

This obviously won't save anything when you have areas of complete darkness, but when it comes to areas that are completely white, the double nested `for` loops that run through the structuring element will only iterate once.  It may save some clock cycles, but always remember that brute-force morphology has already terrible computational complexity as it is.

Comment: the correction works. thanks for pointing out. Even i'm wondering how i haven't got segmentation faults!! And the optimization at last reduces the run time by more than 50% in this case. nice suggestion!

Comment: @avr - Ah that's the thing with allocated memory lol.  It's a tricky business.  Sometimes accessing that element in that undefined location works, and sometimes it doesn't.  You would have definitely gotten an error if that array is stored in the stack (i.e. declaring an array of a known size at compile-time), not the heap (i.e. dynamically allocating the array at run-time).

Comment: @rayryeng, it seems you're into Image Processing - could you assist us open this dedicated group: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/66531/computer-vision/72084 Just vote to questions with less than 10 up votes. Thanks.

Comment: @Drazick - It seems that way doesn't it?  I voted for the CV StackExchange proposal a while ago as well as voting for the questions.  Just waiting for it to get approved!

Comment: @rayryeng, You answer to a lot of people, would you suggest them to assist as well? How about helping me making it Image Processing and Computer Vision forum?

Comment: @Drazick - That sounds promising.  I may even apply to be a moderator for that forum.  I'll see what I can do!

Comment: @rayryeng, Could you support the name change (Adding Image Processing to the forum name in addition to Computer Vision): http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/17733/computer-vision-vs-computer-vision-and-image-processing

Comment: @Drazick - I saw that post when I was there a few minutes ago.  I upvoted your answer.